# An error occurred attempting to determine the process ID which is hosting your application. An error occurred while sending the request

Tags: visual-studio, iis-express

this started happening suddenly.

In a Visual Studio 2022 solution I have 2 .NET Core projects which are web applications.

Both are configured to run in IIS Express.

`launchSettings.json` of "Project A" contains this:

```
{
  "profiles": {
    "http": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5164"
    },
    "https": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7190;http://localhost:5164"
    },
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "ancmHostingModel": "OutOfProcess"
    }
  },
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:59140",
      "sslPort": 44369
    }
  }
}
```

And that file of "Project B" contains this:

```
{
  "profiles": {
    "http": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5191"
    },
    "https": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7255;http://localhost:5191"
    },
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "ancmHostingModel": "OutOfProcess"
    }
  },
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:59150",
      "sslPort": 44375
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is that when I try to debug "Project B", the error `An error occurred attempting to determine the process ID which is hosting your application. An error occurred while sending the request.` is shown.

When I run "Project A", it is run without problems. Browser opens and the home page is shown.

By running the command `netsh http show sslcert` I can see that 44375 port is listed.

Furthermore, if I run `"c:\Program Files\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe" /config:applicationhost.config /site:MySite`, IIS Express starts without problems when I have this binding in applicationHost.config file:

```
    <bindings>
      <binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:59150:localhost" />
    </bindings>
```

> Starting IIS Express ... Successfully registered URL
> "https://localhost:59150/" for site "EntryPortal.Core" application "/"
> Registration completed for site "EntryPortal.Core" IIS Express is
> running. Enter 'Q' to stop IIS Express

If I change binding to 44375 port, ths error is shown:

> Starting IIS Express ... Failed to register URL
> "https://localhost:44375/" for site "EntryPortal.Core" application
> "/". Error description: El proceso no tiene acceso al archivo porque
> estß siendo utilizado por otro proceso. (0x80070020) IIS Express is
> running. Enter 'Q' to stop IIS Express

Even when there is no other process listening on that port.

How can I solve it?

Comment: Cannot reproduce the issue with the description you gave. A few things you might consider: 1) new web projects created by VS2022 no longer add IIS/IIS Express profiles, so that indicates the trend. 2. Using the same port number in multiple web projects is well known to be troublesome. Any particular reason to do that?